# Get attendance by location(gps) with android

Tags: android, .net

Hi I'm beginner developer(still student) I created an **employee management system** in vb.net and I want to get **attendance** of employee by android app with gps and store the emp- information at the system(vb.net)

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is, or what assistance you require. Please elaborate on what you've done so far, or what documentation you've consulted.

Comment: @Vinnie 
Ok simply I have employee management system and I want to get the attendance of my employee